# dual Javascript counter not possible?

Tags: javascript, counter

I have a tiny php file which has only a div and a countdown javascript on it. Here is the code:

```
        <b><div id="COUNTER"></div></b>
        <SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
        var TargetCOUNTER = document.getElementById('COUNTER');
        //HIER DIE SEKUNDEN EINTRAGEN HERR REUTER !!
        var SecondsCOUNTER = 5654;
        //------------------------------------------
        var TargetTimeCOUNTER = new Date();
        var TimeBeginnCOUNTER = TargetTimeCOUNTER.getTime();
        var TimeEndCOUNTER = TimeBeginnCOUNTER + (SecondsCOUNTER*1000);
        TargetTimeCOUNTER.setTime(TimeEndCOUNTER);

        var DayCOUNTER = TargetTimeCOUNTER.getDate();
        var MonthCOUNTER = TargetTimeCOUNTER.getMonth() + 1;
        var YearCOUNTER = TargetTimeCOUNTER.getYear();
        if(YearCOUNTER < 999) YearCOUNTER += 1900;
        var hCOUNTER = TargetTimeCOUNTER.getHours();
        var mCOUNTER = TargetTimeCOUNTER.getMinutes();
        var sCOUNTER = TargetTimeCOUNTER.getSeconds();

        var fdayCOUNTER  = ((DayCOUNTER < 10) ? "0" : "");
        var fmonthCOUNTER  = ((MonthCOUNTER < 10) ? ".0" : ".");
        var fhCOUNTER  = ((hCOUNTER < 10) ? "0" : "");
        var fmCOUNTER  = ((mCOUNTER < 10) ? ":0" : ":");
        var fsCOUNTER  = ((sCOUNTER < 10) ? ":0" : ":");

        var EndDateCOUNTER = fdayCOUNTER + DayCOUNTER + fmonthCOUNTER + MonthCOUNTER  + "." + YearCOUNTER;
        var EndTimeCOUNTER = fhCOUNTER+hCOUNTER+fmCOUNTER+mCOUNTER+fsCOUNTER+sCOUNTER;

        CountDownCOUNTER();
        function CountDownCOUNTER() {
            var CurrentDateCOUNTER = new Date();
            var CurrentTimeCOUNTER = CurrentDateCOUNTER.getTime()
            var OpenTimeCOUNTER = Math.floor((TargetTimeCOUNTER-     CurrentTimeCOUNTER)/1000);

            var sCOUNTER = OpenTimeCOUNTER % 60;
            var mCOUNTER = ((OpenTimeCOUNTER-sCOUNTER)/60) % 60;
            var hCOUNTER = ((OpenTimeCOUNTER-sCOUNTER-mCOUNTER*60)/(60*60));
            var fhCOUNTER  = ((hCOUNTER < 10) ? "0" : "");
            var fmCOUNTER  = ((mCOUNTER < 10) ? ":0" : ":");
            var fsCOUNTER  = ((sCOUNTER < 10) ? ":0" : ":");

            var TimeCOUNTER = fhCOUNTER+hCOUNTER+fmCOUNTER+mCOUNTER+fsCOUNTER+sCOUNTER;
            var OutputStringCOUNTER=TimeCOUNTER;

            if(OpenTimeCOUNTER<=0) { // Event wenn der Countdown abgelaufen ist
                OutputStringCOUNTER="<a href='../hackerz/fight.php' style='text-decoration: none; color: #00ff00'>Aktualisieren</a>";
            }

            TargetCOUNTER.innerHTML=OutputStringCOUNTER; // Ausgabe des Strings in der Betreffenden Zelle
            document.title=(OutputStringCOUNTER.substring(0,2)=="<a")?"!!!READY!!!":OutputStringCOUNTER;
            window.setTimeout("CountDownCOUNTER()",1000);
        }
    </SCRIPT>
```

It works very well. You can check it out here: http://dev.willstequatschen.de/hw/sites/hackerz/counter.php

But I want to display 2 rows with different counters, when I copy and paste the code tiwce, the second counter is not displayed. Why is that?

Comment: I recommend you to learn some basic Javascript programming. If you don't, you are going to have hundreds of problems like this one in the future.

Comment: Because the timers and their code aren't object based. All of the variables it needs are global variables. When you define the 2nd counter you overwrite the variables that the first one uses. You could make the variables and functions needed by the counter part of another javascript object, rather than the window object (like you do now). That is to say - convert the code to be object-oriented.

Comment: `//HIER DIE SEKUNDEN EINTRAGEN HERR REUTER !!` (EN: *Input seconds here Mr. Reuter*) Where should Mr. Reuter enter the seconds if that are two counters? As one variable can only carry one value, you can not use it for two different counters at the same time if those two counters need two different values at once. Just think about it a little.

Comment: //var SecondsCOUNTER = 5654; wird ersetzt durch eine php variable: //var SecondsCOUNTER = <? $variable ?>;

Comment: @Ajin: The question was less technically, but logically. You can create two counters with the same script by using two browsewr-windows or tabs. That would work. (I know you don't want that, but just to give the example what is happening here)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap all your code in a single function accepting an id of the counter container:

```
function setCounter(id) {
    var TargetCOUNTER = document.getElementById(id);
    // rest of your code here
}
```

Call this function for each counter separately:

```
setCounter('COUNTER1');
setCounter('COUNTER2');
```

See demo http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/CdeGs/

Comment: I fit in antother parameter. The seconds:
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CdeGs/2/)

Answer (score 0):

If you just copy and paste the code both copies will work on `<div id="COUNTER"></div>` (which means there will only be one counter).

You will need to change your code to have 2 counter divs and have your `CountDownCOUNTER` function take it as a parameter or make it update both.

Answer (score 0):

Odds are you need to change the ID of the copy from "COUNTER" to something else unique.. You'll need to change it in both the original  tag, as well as the top of the JS' "GetElementbyID".

In fact, based on the way the code looks, might be best to just do a global Search & Replace on the entire 2nd copy for "COUNTER" to "ALTCOUNTER" or something different, to prevent collisions with the variables & function name.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not really object-oriented or written with reusability in-mind, so you can use only a single instance this way.

The recommended way is to rewrite your code in a more abstract and component-style way, like a  "plugin" for example.

Maybe you should drop your code and use some ready-made solution.

The dirty approach that you can do is to load your counters in an individual iframes - it will solve the scope clashing problem, but i wouldn't recommend it really.